# How to lock Record(unable to Edit) in saleforce

Tags: validation-rule

I've one checkbox field `Completed`. which is update by using apex class.

I've created one checkbox field as `Record Locked`  when this field is checked true then; user unable to edit the record. i've to update `Record Locked` field automatically

when i write validation and check for the `Record Locked` is true; The problem is when i try to check `Record Locked` to true then validation also fire.

How can we do. Please Suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have to lock the record in Salesforce we can use Approval Process. it is one of way

We can use Process builder + Approval Process.

[Click Here](http://www.jdope.com/blog/lock-a-record-using-process-builder-and-a-dummy-approval-process/) to see steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PRIORVALUE` function to check the **Record Locked's** old value in your validate rule to prevent firing the VR at first time.